# Flutter FCM onBackgroundMessage handler gives null check error

Tags: firebase, flutter, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to implement notifications for my app, but when initializing notifications `FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(notificationHandler)`gives error

Error:

E/flutter (28265): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value
E/flutter (28265): #0      MethodChannelFirebaseMessaging.registerBackgroundMessageHandler (package:firebase_messaging_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_messaging.dart:173:53)
E/flutter (28265): #1      FirebaseMessagingPlatform.onBackgroundMessage= (package:firebase_messaging_platform_interface/src/platform_interface/platform_interface_messaging.dart:108:16)
E/flutter (28265): #2      FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage (package:firebase_messaging/src/messaging.dart:100:31)

notificationHandler:

```dart
Future<void> notificationHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
    /// do sth with data
}
```

Note: `FirebaseMessaging.onMessage` and `FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp` works without error

Comment: initializing ònBackgroundMessage`on the main function solved the issue

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems that you are putting `FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(notificationHandler)` along with `notificationHandler` function within a class. However, that contradicts with the official docs of FlutterFire [here](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/usage/#background-messages). You need to fulfill these conditions for this function to work properly:

1. It must not be an anonymous function.
2. It must be *a top-level function* (e.g. not a class method which requires initialization).

My suggestion to you is that try to put the function `notificationHandler` that you are using as an argument **outside** the class that you are calling `FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage()` from. It worked with me.